# unable to implement interface member because it does not have the matching return type

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have some troubles with interface and inheritance. Here my problem :

I have two interfaces :

```
public interface IElementA
{
    List<IElementA> Child { get; }
}

// The goal is to add some properties to the main interface
public interface IElementB : IElementA
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

and a class which implement IElementB

```
public class ElementB : IElementB
{
    protected List<ElementB> m_Child = new List<ElementB>();

    public List<ElementB> Child { get { return m_Child; } }
    public string Name { get { return "element B"; }
}
```

Then I got the error:

> 'ElementB' does not implement interface membre 'IElementA.Child'.
>
> 'ELementB.Child' cannot implement 'IElementA.Child' because it does not have the matching return type of 'List<IElementA>'."

I understand that I need to write

```
public List<IElementA> Child { get { return m_Child; } }
```

And know the template trick but it's work only with a List of different type of IElementA.

Do you have some ideas to solve my problem ?

Best Regards
JM

Comment: `List<IElementA>` is not the same type as `List<ElementB>` which is why you get the compilation error.

Comment: look at *Covariance*

Comment: DavidG has the correct answer

Comment: Yes after a good night DavidG has correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics:

```
public interface IElementA<T>
{
    List<T> Child { get; }
}

public interface IElementB
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class ElementB : IElementA<ElementB>, IElementB
{
    protected List<ElementB> m_Child = new List<ElementB>();

    public List<ElementB> Child { get { return m_Child; } }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "element B"; }
    }

}
```

---

or if you really see inheritance here (I don't):

```
public interface IElementB<T> : IElementA<T> where T: IElementA<T> ...

public class ElementB : IElementB<ElementB> ...
```

Comment: This lets you specify any type for T though, it's not as constrained as OPs code. (not my DV though)

Comment: @DavidG, see edit, I am not quite sure what I am doing at this time of day. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you respect the Iterface implementation your list will look to :

```
    protected List<IElementA> m_Child = new List<IElementA>();
    public List<IElementA> Child { get { return m_Child; } }
```

So you will be able to add ElementB element into it :

```
this.m_Child.Add(new ElementB());
```

If you want only `ElementB` in this list, check the type before insertion on it.